# Monadic API with "backpane" values

Tags: haskell, monads, api-design, clash

I'm creating a library for describing the connection of address lines to memory elements. I think a monadic API would work very nicely for creating components (with an identity, to support mirroring), and then using those component handles at various restricted address ranges; e.g:

```
(dataIn, ()) = memoryMap _addrOut _dataOut $ do
    rom <- romFromFile (SNat @0x2000) "SpaceInvaders.bin"
    ram <- ram0 (SNat @0x0400)

    from 0x0000 $ connect rom
    from 0x2000 $ connect ram
    from 0x4000 $ connect ram
```

However, some memory components also have "backpane connections". For example, suppose a memory-mapped IO peripheral has a byte output. I could represent that as a monadic action that returns a pair of a result: the memory element handle, and the output signal; and then leave it to the user to route it somehow to the end result of the whole memory mapping description:

```
(dataIn, outByte) = memoryMap _addrOut _dataOut $ do
    rom <- romFromFile (SNat @0x0800) "_build/intel8080/image.bin"
    ram <- ram0 (SNat @0x1800)
    (acia, outByte) <- port $ acia inByte outReady

    matchLeft $ do
        from 0x10 $ connect acia
    matchRight $ do
        from 0x0000 $ connect rom
        from 0x0800 $ connect ram

    return outByte
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't admit an easy implementation. In the background, these components are ultimately just `Signal addr -> Signal (Maybe dat) -> (Signal dat, Signal backpane)` functions, so to get the `backpane` signal, I need to apply them on an `addr` signal; this of course requires looking at all the subsequent `connect` calls on the handle. This needs [a messy "knot-tying" implementation](https://github.com/gergoerdi/retroclash-lib/blob/a304e25567a581f57770d77541e62fa0f78ff952/src/RetroClash/Memory.hs#L65) that [causes problems further downstream](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/1536), so I'd like to avoid it.

Also, the user isn't really able to do anything with these backpane outputs like `outByte`, other than returning them at the end. So it would be cleaner if only the handles (like `rom`, `ram` and `acia` in the examples above) were bound, and other outputs were... somehow... magically... transported to the outside.

What I mean by that is that instead of applying the individual memory components on this recursively defined address line, creating a memory component could just return some opaque handle, hold on to that function to be applied after all the `connect` calls, and then apply it. No recursion needed, no backpane values are exposed to the user, etc. But how *would* these extra outputs be ultimately collected?

As I am writing this question, one idea that pops to mind is using a graded monad where the index is the list of types of backpane output signals; creating the `acia` handle, for example, would extend that list by a new element. The runner `memoryMap` would return some kind of generalized product type alongside the memory read result. But I don't like this idea for two reasons:

- Using a graded monad is unwieldy for the user, you need to use `RebindableSyntax` to recover `do` notation, type inference isn't so good, and overall it's just a pain to explain to users.
- The eventual type of `memoryMap` would be surprising because it would depend on the order in which components with backpane signals are created.

Comment: Instead of an indexed monad, perhaps you could use a monad parameterized by a type-level list of names/types. (Possibly requiring a type signature or type application from the user.) The monad would carry as state some kind of extensible record indexed by the list. Commands which created "backpane connections" would require a type application with the name (or index) of the particular port. This wouldn't enforce that all the ports mentioned in type-level list are given values though. Perhaps the missing ports could be given some kind of "neutral" value, if it makes sense.